# Is it possible to crossreference / link to a numbered list item, in ReStructuredText?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

##### The ReST autonumbering problem

In `.rst` files, item lists can be created with a syntax that allows for autonumbering.

Handy, but it's exactly that convenience that makes referring to other items in the list a fraught undertaking. If a list item is referenced by number, it's all too easy for someone to later update the list, causing a renumbering, and *neglect* to update the item-reference. (Assuming it's even close enough to **be** noticed.) For example:

```rst
Item Franchise
==============

#. *Item*

#. Prequel: *Birth of Item*

#. *Son of Item*

#. *Item III: The Enumerating*

#. *Item Jr.*\ , a Remake of *Son of Item* (see item 2, above)
```

Obviously, the last entry should be referencing "item 3, above", but the author forgot about *Birth of Item* (or it was subsequently added to the list).

How do I know that's a concern? Well, besides the fact that it's obvious (for many of the same reasons that manual page-number references are a headache), I just [opened a PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/100286) against the Python documentation, correcting exactly such an error that's gone unnoticed for the past three years.

##### Is there a better way?

I'll be very surprised if the answer to this is "yes", but is there any way to define item references in ReST so that it'll maintain them automatically, changing the referenced target-item number whenever the list ordering changes? Or perhaps someone's come up with a Sphinx extension along those lines?

If *not*, I'd certainly be interested in any clever suggestions for better ways to refer both *to* and *between* items in an ordered list. (Assume a situation more like the Python doc error, **not** my example where the "titles" are incredibly obvious crossref opportunities.)

Comment: *"changing the referenced target-item number whenever the list ordering changes?"* - No because the numbering isn't part of the reference. If you check the ReST spec a numbered list and a reference target are different, unrelated elements. So, unless someone publishes a custom directive there's no builtin magic reference that picks up the list number if the reference happens to be inside a numbered list. I'm not aware of the existence of such a Sphinx extension.

Comment: @bad_coder Yeah, that sounds like about what I expected, alas. There is a _sort of_ precedent in the way the `:numref:` role works with `numfig` enabled, but even then it's still a **linked** reference (the only type, I suspect, that ReST supports) and I suppose executing `numfig`-type logic on every _individual item_ of every ordered list, just on the off chance that the document might want to reference one of them somewhere, would add an awful lot of mostly-wasted work for the builder. Not to mention all the extra markup generated.

Comment: Using `:numref:` the role works by keeping its own index for the entire document, there's no HTML element for enumerated lists that keeps the count across separate lists. Besides, `:numref:` apparently only works with structural and body elements, not list elements.

Comment: @bad_coder Oh, sure, but `:numref:` numbering can be per-section, for example, so structurally if it can figure out which figure is "3.4" and reference it that way, then it could track that a particular `<li>` is item N in list M as well. `<li>` tags can have `id` attributes, like any other, and you can link to individual `<li id="…">` items using URL fragments, like any other. So _in theory_ they could all be uniquely identified and referenceable. ...Anyway, i think ultimately we're agreeing with each other, even if it's theoretically possible that doesn't mean it's a good idea.